# Does fenced-in privately owned land require an eruv?

Tags: shabbat, eruv-chatzerot

Take a privately owned campground (not part of a national or state park) that is surrounded by a fence at least 1m (roughly 10 *tefamim*) tall.  The campground's main gate is a typical vehicle gate -- essentially a pair of poles that block the road, and when closed is less than 1m above the ground.

For Shabbat purposes, does this campground count as a single private domain?  Or is an eruv necessary to permit carrying (such as bringing water and food on a hike within the campground)?

I believe that the situation I describe would apply to any plot of land with a similar fence, regardless of the type of property (such as a back yard).  I also believe, though not as confidently, that the answer to my question would also apply to a similarly enclosed national- or state-owned campground.  I welcome comments that address these statements.

I've done my basic research on *reshut hayachid* and *eruv chatzerot*, but so far have not found a clear answer to my question.  I've determined that a wall with gates may enclose a private domain, but I'm unclear whether open fencework (such as a wire fence or split-rail fence) counts as a "wall" for this purpose.  I have not yet found any rules defining a permissible gate, just a permissible doorway for a *tzurat hapetach*.  I am also aware that for a proper ruling I must CMLOR.

Comment: Every set of walls/gates is different. There is no general answer to this sort of question.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is there a general guideline?

Comment: There are halachos of gates that are made of spokes and/or ropes. As long as they’re within 3 tefachim of each other, there’sa din of lavud. The other point that needs clarification though, is if the people staying on these grounds are guests of the owner, or if they’re paying like a hotel and have their own places.

Comment: @Chatzkel: In the specific case I have in mind, the group is paying for the space.  But I am curious how the answers differ in the two cases.

Comment: If there are many people renting out the space then they would need to make an eiruv, not a fence, an eiruv, as in using the bread/matza etc an actually making the eiruv. As far as a fence, a chainlink fence is considered enough since the holes are less than 3 tefachim from each other.